# FME issue while updating AND inserting data in Esri Geodatabase (File Geodb) writer

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, esri-geodatabase, fme-transformer

I have a geodatabase file to update with FME Desktop : some features must be updated, et some new features must be inserted in that geodatabase file. Those features are polygons with several attributes.

First in my script, I read the geodatabase file. Then I change some values and create new ones.

Finally, I use a "Esri Geodatabase (File Geodb)" writer to update former data and insert new data at the same time. I chose feature opeartion "upsert" and table handling "create if needed".

When I open the resulting "updated" gdb file in Arcgis Pro, I can see the updated data and... only part of the new features. There are several of them missing ! But why ?

Here is what I should have :
[image: what i should have]

And here is what I get :
[image: what i get]

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already encountered this issue; it was due to excessive/duplicate nodes in some of the polygons. Check even the "full" polygons, sometime the missing features change with the scale or the position on the screen, like a display bug.

Comment: Indeed, when using a Geometry Validator, those features failed the validation. They have a "duplicated rings" issue. Is there a way to repair this in FME ?

Comment: I used a Deagregator and used a sampler to keep only the first polygon extracted. Thanks !